# Pyramid Mako pserver --reload not reloading in Mac

Tags: python, pyramid, mako, waitress

I've a strange issue. pserve --reload has stopped reloading the templates. It is reloading if some .py-file is changing, but won't notice .mak-file changes anymore.

I tried to fix it by:

- Checking the filepermissions
- Creating the new virtualenv, which didn't help.
- Installing different version of mako without any effect.
- Checking that the python is used from virtualenv
- playing with the development.ini. It has the flag: pyramid.reload_templates = true

Any idea how to start debugging the system?

Versions:

- Python 2.7
- pyramid 1.5
- pyramid_mako 1.02
- mako 0.9.1

Yours
Heikki

Comment: Also the pserve's reload-interval won't help

Answer (score 1):

This looks like https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_mako/issues/19  Perhaps file an issue on GitHub.  Also try hitting #pyramid on irc.freenode.net.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my,

I found the thing... I had <%block cached="True"  cache_key="${self.filename}+body"> and the file inclusion was inside of that block.

Cheerious:)